# VARCHAR in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query that runs in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(T.Texte) 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         CONVERT(varchar(8000), CONVERT(binary(8000), USER_DATA)) AS Texte 
     FROM 
         O_USER_DATA ) T
WHERE
    T.Texte LIKE '%test123%'
```

In Oracle it doesn't compile. I get an exception:

> missing expression

How to modify my query so it will run in an Oracle database?

Comment: What does `CONVERT(varchar(8000), CONVERT(binary(8000), USER_DATA))` do? What data type is `user_data`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, user_data is of type varBinary(max). The query converts that data into "simple" varchar.

Comment: There is no type `varbinary(max)` in Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, true, but there is one in MSSQL. I wish to change my query so it will work in Oracle

Comment: The correct query depends on the data type of the column `user_data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2` function, since what you store in `user_data` column can be stored within a `BLOB` type column for Oracle, and that function might be used in order to convert the content to `VARCHAR2` type :

```
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(user_data) AS Texte 
   FROM O_USER_DATA 
) 
SELECT COUNT(t.Texte) 
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=83c000fe02a44a29f43dd61872c2b026)</kbd>